# Why isn't the output recognized with the promotion?

Tags: python, openmdao

I am trying to change from ''connect'' to ''promotes'' for paraboloid example (without constraint) and I receive the output error. 
**Output not found for response 'parab.f_xy' in system ''.**

Feel free to have a look at the code below, I tried to make it similar to the topic explained in the ""Linking Variables with Promotion vs. Connection"". The code is independent from the released paraboloid component.

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, IndepVarComp
from openmdao.core.explicitcomponent import ExplicitComponent

class Paraboloid(ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

        self.declare_partials('*', '*')
    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['x']
        y = inputs['y']
        outputs['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        x = inputs['x']
        y = inputs['y']
        partials['f_xy', 'x'] = 2.0*x - 6.0 + y
        partials['f_xy', 'y'] = 2.0*y + 8.0 + x

# build the model
prob = Problem()
indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
indeps.add_output('x', 3.0)
indeps.add_output('y', -4.0)

prob.model.add_subsystem('parab', Paraboloid(), promotes_inputs=['x','y'] , promotes_outputs=['f_xy'])

# setup the optimization
prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_objective('parab.f_xy')

prob.setup()
prob.run_driver()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you promoted 'f_xy' up from the 'parab' component, your objective should now be named 'f_xy' instead of 'parab.f_xy', and because you promoted 'x' and 'y' up from the 'indeps' component, your design variables should be named 'x' and 'y' instead of 'indeps.x' and 'indeps.y'.